# Angular: ng-show isn't evaluating expression continuously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a variable called `activeScope` to maintain state and toggle between two forms. This variable changes value when a tab is clicked by invoking `changeScope` to update.

This change is registered correctly to toggle between the active states of the tab buttons, but the divs `form0` and `form1` do not toggle at all. From what I see, it seems that I'm not using `ng-show` correctly as the expression isn't evaluating when the value of `activeScope` changes.

Here are my tabs -

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="SearchScope as scope">
    <li ng-repeat="item in scopes" ng-class="{'active': isScopeActive({{$index}})}"><a href="" ng-click="changeScope($index)">{{item}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have my markup for the div's as -

```
<div class="container main-form" ng-controller="SearchScope as scope">
    <div id="form0" ng-show="isScopeActive(0)" ng-controller="SingleIPController as sip">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="form1" ng-show="isScopeActive(1)">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller code -

```
app.controller("SearchScope", function($scope) {
    $scope.activeScope = 0;
    $scope.scopes = ['Individual IP Data', 'All IP Data'];

    $scope.isScopeActive = function(index){
        if(index == $scope.activeScope){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    $scope.changeScope = function(index){
        $scope.activeScope = index;
    };
});

app.controller("SingleIPController", function($scope, $http){
    ...
});
```

Could someone please advise if what I'm doing with `ng-show` is wrong and the correct way to go about this problem?

Comment: Please wrap your entire code up in an additional `div`-tag and apply `ng-controller="SearchScope as scope"` on it. You're trying to instantiate the same controller twice in your example. You most likely only want it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by following an approach similar to the one at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jasoncluck/pen/iDcbh). It is almost like what I wanted to achieve - Master-Detail pattern.

Markup -

```
<div class="container" ng-app="tabApp">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="TabController">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(1) }">
                <a href ng-click="setTab(1)">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(2) }">
                <a href ng-click="setTab(2)">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(3) }">
                <a href ng-click="setTab(3)">Messages</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="jumbotron">
            <div ng-show="isSet(1)">
                <h1>Home page</h1>
                <p>Welcome to the website!</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="isSet(2)">
            <h1>Profile page</h1>
            <p>Profile information</p>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="isSet(3)">
            <h1>Messages</h1>
            <p> Some messages </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller -

```
angular.module('tabApp', [])
.controller('TabController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.setTab = function(newTab){
        $scope.tab = newTab;
    };

    $scope.isSet = function(tabNum){
        return $scope.tab === tabNum;
    };
}]);
```

CSS -

```
@import "compass/css3";

body {
margin: 15px;
}

/* text recolor */
h1, p, a {
color: #4DC9C9 !important;
}

/* button recolor */
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .btn-primary {
background-color: #6C6C6C !important;
// feeling like it's a rounded corners kind of day
border-color: #6C6C6C !important;
border-radius: 25px; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes this is not the quite right usage of ng-show. Here is a working demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/agm7pmyw/1/

code:

```
<div id="search-container" ng-controller="SearchScope">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li ng-repeat="item in scopes" ng-class="{'active' : $index == activeScope}">
      <a href="" ng-click="changeScope($index)">{{item}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="container main-form">
    <div id="form0" ng-show="activeScope == 0" ng-controller="SingleIPController as sip">
      Scope 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container main-form">
    <div id="form1" ng-show="activeScope == 1" ng-controller="SingleIPController as sip">
      Scope 2
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

script:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("SearchScope", function($scope) {
  $scope.activeScope = 0;
  $scope.scopes = ['Individual IP Data', 'All IP Data'];

  $scope.isScopeActive = function(index) {
    if (index == $scope.activeScope) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  $scope.changeScope = function(index) {
    console.log('changing scope to ' + index);
    $scope.activeScope = index;
  };
});

app.controller("SingleIPController", function($scope, $http) {

});
```

css:

```
.active{
  color:red
}
```

I did change your markup a little bit, you can play with the demo.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`ng-show` does not call a function rather evaluates the expression there itself. Hence, modify your code accordingly.

In your controller create a boolean variable which keeps track of the selected type(0=> false, 1=>true). Inside your view, check this vvariable using ng-show to show or hide the form accordingly.

Controller Code :

```
$scope.showForm1 = false;
$scope.changeScope = function(index){
    if(index == 0)
        $scope.showForm1 = false;
    else
        $scope.showForm1 = true;
};
```

In your view:

```
<div class="container main-form" ng-controller="SearchScope as scope">
<div id="form0" ng-show="!showForm1" ng-controller="SingleIPController as sip">
...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container main-form" ng-controller="SearchScope as scope">
  <div id="form1" ng-show="showForm1" ng-controller="SingleIPController as sip">
...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't do this because the number of scopes may increase to 3 or more